# Local highest score unity android

Tags: android

Hello everyone i am new into unity and need help, below is codes of my current score and highest scores, the current score is showing into gameover menu but highest score is always 0.

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using System.Collections;

public class SetScore : MonoBehaviour {

```
public GameObject newRecordText;
public GUIText thisScoreObj ;
public GUIText thisHighScoreObj ;

void Start () {
    int score = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("currentScore");
    int highScoreOld = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highestScoreOld");

    newRecordText.SetActive (false);

    if (score > highScoreOld) {
        newRecordText.SetActive(true);
    }

    thisScoreObj.text = "" + score;
    thisHighScoreObj.text = "" + highScoreOld;

    AdjustFontSize ();
}

void AdjustFontSize() {
    if(Screen.height > 480 && Screen.width > 800){
        thisScoreObj.fontSize = 60;
        thisHighScoreObj.fontSize = 60;
    }

    else if(Screen.height <= 480 && Screen.width <= 800)        {
        thisScoreObj.fontSize = 40;
        thisHighScoreObj.fontSize = 40;
    }
}
```

}

```
void start() {
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("highestScore")) {
                    highestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highestScore");     
                    highestScoreOld = highestScore;
            } else { 
        highestScore = 0;
        highestScoreOld = highestScore;
    }
}

void gameOver(int score) {
    //Debug.Log ("GAME OVER!!! Your score: " + score);
    Application.LoadLevel("GameOverMenu");
    if (score > highestScore) {
        highestScore = score;       
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currentScore", score);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScore", highestScore);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScoreOld", highestScoreOld);



}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I think you should call Application.LoadLevel("GameOverMenu"); at the end of the method. You are loading a new scene before the method is fully completed. Here's the modified one -

```
void gameOver(int score) {
    //Debug.Log ("GAME OVER!!! Your score: " + score);
    if (score > highestScore) {
        highestScore = score;       
    }
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currentScore", score);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScore", highestScore);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScoreOld", highestScoreOld);
    Application.LoadLevel("GameOverMenu");
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Imtiaj Ahmed, Thanks for posting but it didn't work, please if anyone know where is the error tell me

Comment: Sorry that it didn't help. But your codes seems to me ok. That's weird. Didn't find anything suspicious.

Comment: Thanks for try to help

Answer (score 0):

i fix it Below !!!

```
void gameOver(int score) {
//Debug.Log ("GAME OVER!!! Your score: " + score);
if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey ("highestScore")) {
                highestScore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("highestScore");     
                highestScoreOld = highestScore;
        } else { 
    highestScore = 0;
    highestScoreOld = highestScore;
}
if (score > highestScore) {
    highestScore = score;       
}
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("currentScore", score);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScore", highestScore);
PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("highestScoreOld", highestScoreOld);
Application.LoadLevel("LoadLevel");
```

}
}